# Squirrel SQL using old path of Java.exe

Tags: java, squirrel-sql

My Squirrel SQL doesn't open when I double click the `.bat` file. (cmd prompt appears and then disappears)
I figured, I had just re installed latest Java version and removed older versions this morning.
How do I change the path to new `Java.exe` in Squirrel config file? And where is this config file for Squirrel SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable points to an existing Java installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this from a windows 10x64 perspective.

The config file squirrel uses for launch is called `squirrel-sql.bat`.  It is located in the same directory as `squirrel-sql.jar`.

The program then sets a variable called `IZPACK_JAVA` with this statement:

```
"IZPACK_JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%"
```

Then it tries to set the `LOCAL JAVA` variable used in the bat program with your `javaw.exe` path so it can continue the start sequence

```
if exist "%IZPACK_JAVA%\bin\javaw.exe" (
  set "LOCAL_JAVA=%IZPACK_JAVA%\bin\javaw.exe"
) else (
  set LOCAL_JAVA=javaw.exe
)
```

If in your current windows installation you don't have the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, create it in the `View advanced system settings` in the control panel.
If you already have it there, just Edit it to make sure the `JAVA HOME` environment variable is pointing either to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre#.#.###` where `jre#.#.###` is the folder version of you java installation folder (preferred option) or to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre#.#.###\bin`.

Should you have multiple java versions installed, you'll need to point `JAVA HOME` to the right version number (depending on what value your `Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion` registry key has).

Another tip is to put in your `PATH` variable the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` value at the beginning of the path values.

After you create or modify your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable path, then restart the computer so it can take effect.

This solved it to me and I was able to run Squirrel after I created and pointed my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the right direction, and I didn't have to delete any `.exe` files in Windows system directories.

This also took care of the error in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697543/registry-key-error-java-version-has-value-1-8-but-1-7-is-required/53192247#53192247) question

> Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion' has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
>
> Error: could not find java.dll
>
> Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Comment: I am using zulu open jdk 15, so I need to replace the %IZPACK_JAVA%(zulu jdk) with other jdk (1.8)