# Registry key Error: Java version has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required

Tags: java, java-8, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

While running

```
sencha app build production
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime
>   Environment'\CurrentVersion'
>
> has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required. Error: could not find java.dll
>   Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

`java -version` , command is showing following:

java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

Not able to find where path is going wrong. Any idea?

----------------------- EDIT ------------------------------------------------

**Note**: I am using Windows 7 (64 bit).

I have tried uninstalling the sencha touch cmd and reinstalling. But still same error.

I have uninstalled all the java version instances and reinstalled the latest one, Still the problem persist.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

After trying more than hundred of tricks, finally got success.

I removed all `java.exe`, `javaw.exe` and `javaws.exe` from my

1. `Windows\System32` and
2. `Windows\SysWOW64` 
   folder. [Try step 2 if you have x64 system (Win 7 64 bits)]

Comment: Win 10 64Bit users: deleting the 3 files in `System32` will solve the issue.

Comment: But we have to close and re-open the cmd and type java -version to view the changes... Worked like a charm thanks!

Comment: @SkepticScribbler: This happens when you somehow confused java itself. You are trying to run a java 7 VM where it found a JRE 8. It might show this problem even if you type in the command line just java or java -version in a misconfigured environment.

Comment: @AnandGupta this is a shot in the dark, not a solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53192247/1423507

Answer (score 49):

In my case (Windows 7 64-bit), I just did the following:

- Removed the reference to **C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;** from the *Path* environment variable
- Removed files **java**, **javaw** and **javaws** from the *C:\Windows\System32* folder

Afterwards, I closed all open command line consoles, reopened them and ran *java -version*.

Comment: I had this issue on Windows 10 when installing JDK5u14, JDK6u34, JDK7u51 and JDK8u121 (in that order). Removing the java files from Windows folder was not sufficient. Had also to remove path from the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 36):

1. open regedit
2. go to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment]`
3. change value `CurrentVersion` from "1.8" to "1.7"

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. I don't have permissions to delete anything under SysWOW64. Simply changing CurrentVersion through regedit solved my problem.

Comment: A much simpler solution than trying to delete all the extraneous java versions!

Comment: .. however, it does not solve anything. Then the installer complains and justly so, that java 8 is required.

Comment: Thanks this solution worked was trying to solve this error for long time

Comment: Warning: It may mess up with your other applications which are configured to use 1.8.

Answer (score 19):

re: Windows users

No. Don't remove the Javapath environment reference from your PATH variable.

The reason why the registry didn't work is that the Oracle Javapath script needs to run in the PATH sequence ahead of the JRE & JDK directories - it will sort out the current version:

put this directory at the HEAD of your `%PATH%` variable:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

[or wherever it is on your desktop]

so your PATH will look something like this - mine for example

```
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;<other path directories>;E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;E:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin
```

You will then see the correct, current version:

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This one works for me. I have Windows 7 (64-bit). I have moved C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath to the beginning of PATH, as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Hey it worked!
Don't forget to restart your computer, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

My experience:

I am using windows **8.1** and i have downgraded JAVA version from 1.8 to 1.7 and i was getting the same error.

**Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Ja has value '1.7', but '1.8' is required.**

I have deleted **java.exe**, **javaw.exe** and **javaws.ex**e from **C:\Windows\System32** folder and it worked for me.

Comment: This will not work if there are other java executables for other Java versions in the path.

Answer (score 11):

I've had the same problem. Simple solution that worked for me is to rearrange the entries in the `PATH` for `JRE/JDK`. This problem started to appear after installing `JRE 8` whose installation has put some executable files in `System32 or SysWOW64` directories, these executable files are messing up. To resolve the problem:

1. Create environment variable pointing to JDK home as `JAVA_HOME`.

   `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_45`
2. Put the entry `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` at start in your PATH environment variable. Appending existing value of `PATH`. For example:

   `path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;%path%`

Comment: this is the best solution if you want to keep multiple versions of java side by side, and if you you don't have the privilege to modify the registry and remove files from the windows\system folder.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't delete any of the java.exe files, but changed the ordering of my System - "path" variable - so that it reflected %JAVA_HOME%\bin as the first entry.
That did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

The error is explicit ...

> Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion' has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
>
> Error: could not find java.dll
>
> Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

... you are attempting to use the `java.exe` 1.7 executable while the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` > `CurrentVersion` registry key has the value 1.8.

The recurring theme to proposed solutions is that the error is a **configuration error**. The error can be solved in various different manners (e.g. reconfiguration of the users environment or removal of java executables with fingers-crossed and hope that there exists another fallback `java.exe` in the users `%PATH%` and that the fallback `java.exe` is the correct executable).

The *correct* solution depends on what you're trying to achieve: "are you trying to downgrade from jdk-8 to jdk-7? Are trying to upgrade to jdk-8? ..."

### Reproduction steps

1. install jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe

> notes:
>
> - the `java.exe` executable available in the users `%PATH%` is installed in `C:\Windows\System32`
> - the installation does not update the users `%PATH%`
> - the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` > `CurrentVersion` string registry entry is created (among others) with the value `1.7`

2. install jdk-8u191-windows-x64.exe

> notes:
>
> - the users `%PATH%` is updated to include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` as the first entry
> - the the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` > `CurrentVersion` string registry entries value is updated to `1.8`

3. update the users `%PATH%` environment variable, remove `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`
4. in a new command prompt `java -version`

> Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
>   has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
>
> Error: could not find java.dll
>
> Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

### Solution(s)

1. OP's solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769311/1423507 is a "fingers-crossed and hope that there exists a fallback `java.exe` in the users `%PATH%` and that the fallback executable is correct" approach to the error. Given the reproduction steps, removing the `java.exe`, `javaw.exe` and `javaws.exe` executables from `C:\Windows\System32` (only in my case) will result in no longer having any `java.exe` present in the users `%PATH%` resulting in the error `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` which is not so much of a solution.
2. answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/35775493/1423507 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36516620/1423507 work however you're reverting to using `java.exe` 1.7 (e.g. update the `CurrentVersion` registry key's value to match the `java.exe` version found in the users `%PATH%`).
3. make sure`java.exe` 1.8 is the first found in the users `%PATH%` (how you do that is irrelevant) i.e.:

   - update the users `%PATH%` to include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` first (ensure that the executables in that directory are correct)
   - update the users `%PATH%` to include the absolute path of your java binaries first (`set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin;%PATH%"`)
   - set java specific environment variables and update the users `%PATH%` with them (`set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java"`; `set JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre1.8.0_191`; `set PATH=%JRE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`)

Comment: @whoever_that_downvotes - this answer can't be enhanced without any constructive feedback. Drop a comment as to "why" and might be able to make this answer better for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error on some windows services running Java.
In the end, on my machine I tried to uninstall the other versions of java.

I left only 1.8 and now everything is working.

Answer (score 2):

aribeiro answer has worked for me - with minor changes

- I Removed the reference to C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; from the Path environment variable
- I made /path/to/jdkhome as the first entry in my PATH environment variable. I think this alone is all that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

As for me on win7 64bit.

Copy the java.exe javaw.exe javaws.exe in the folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin to the C:\Windows\System32.`

and then open cmd, type java -version.

```
C:\Users\HEcom>java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Before the above make sure the Registry's CurrentVersion is 1.8

In the START menu type "regedit" to open the Registry editor

1. Go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" on the left-hand side registry
   explorer/tree menu
2. Click "SOFTWARE" within the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" registries
3. Click "JavaSoft" within the "SOFTWARE" registries
4. Click "Java Runtime Environment" within the "JavaSoft" list of
   registries here you can see different versions of installed java
5. Click "Java Runtime Environment"- On right hand side you will get
   4-5 rows . Please select "CurrentVersion" and right Click( select
   modify option) make sure the version is "1.8"

Comment: This is a really bad idea. The binaries folder must be added to path instead of moving files to a folder already in path. It can cause a horrible headache if someone else has to update java on the system and has not knowledge about this "solution". And that's exactly the op's problem source... Fix your path instead.

Comment: Change *I just MOVE* into *I just COPY* and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this problem came after reading and trying all of the above.

In my case I tried to downgrade Java to use printouts in `Apache ActiveMQ`. After uninstalling all Java versions and cleaning the registry I was getting the same error

> Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
>   has value '1.7', but '1.8' is required."

In my case I needed to go to environment variables, edit path, open the javapath location (`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`) and there it was - three files (`java.exe`, `javaw.exe`, `javaws.exe`) that remained from the JRE8 version.

After establishing this fact I simply switched them with the same files from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` directory (those were from the `JRE7` version) and it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

After the latest automatic Java update, I could not run Java from the command prompt.

My path variable had 'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;'

I could not cd into 'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;' from the command prompt window, since it did not exist.

I removed C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;' from the path variable and replaced it with 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin;'

Comment: This is much more a comment than an answer. The question is about a very specific tool, and making very clear that java is in deed found.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define your jdk folder in variable JAVA_HOME, 
add %JAVA_HOME% to your variable path

Delete or change name of your java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws in your folder system32

execute cmd.exe, java -version now take the new version that you define in JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Anand Gupta's answer, make sure no other java except for the one you need is used.
Run `which java` (`where java` for Windows) and see which java executables are used.
Just delete the ones you don't want to use and if the one you need is not present, add it to PATH.

Answer (score 1):

First you should have Java 7. If you don't have, install it first (I don't know what you are using, Linux, Mac, yum, apt, homebrew, you should find out yourself.)

If you already have Java 7, run:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Output should be something like this:`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`. Near this directory, you should see `java-7` directory. After you found it, run

```
export JAVA_HOME=${java-7-dir}
```

Change `{java-7-dir}` with your directory path. Then you can run your command.

**This is only a temporary solution.** To change it permanently, put the above command to your `~/.bashrc` file.

**EDIT: If you are using Windows**, change environment variable of `JAVA_HOME` to your Java 7 installation directory path.

Comment: @AnandGupta I added Windows case.

Comment: In case of Linux, you need to provide the path to the Java binary in JAVA_HOME. For example, /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java. In case of Windows, just the installation directory should do.

Answer (score 1):

My short contribution, for sharing the same problem with Talend Open Studio 64 bit version.

1. Launch ..\TOS_DI-Win32-20150702_1326-V6.0.0\TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe manually (not link an startup Windows menu)
2. and this registry error message appears

To resolve this, remove all java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe files on c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\

and TOS start with 64 bits version correctly !

Answer (score 1):

Remove it from the System path:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

And it will fix the issue in upgrading java version from 1.7 to 1.8

Comment: Could you tell us why?

Answer (score 1):

There exist somewhere another java.exe from jre version 1.8 that it is in "path"
you should find and delete it if it is possible. it may be in user tempdata for applications that need jre.

Answer (score 1):

Please change JAVA_BIN and JAVA_HOME system variable, and then restart system or maybe relogin. You are having that error because it is still jdk1.7 path. On windows it is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have had the similar problem. Moving the JDK and JRE path to the top of the path variable solved the problem (which takes first priority over what is present under System32)

For example, here is mine:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just Install Java SE Runtime Environment JRE 7 !

Now you see "java 7" & "java 8" in "Programs and Features" in the "Control Panel"

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to this problem is to add at Sencha CMD folder a bat file as sugested at this thread [Sencha Cmd 5 + Java 8 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786159/sencha-cmd-5-java-8-error).

The batch will have the name "sencha.bat" with this code:

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=<YOUR JDK 7 HOME>
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set SENCHA_HOME=%~dp0
java -jar "%SENCHA_HOME%\sencha.jar" %*
```

Place it at sencha folder, in my case is

```
C:\Users\<YOUR USER>\bin\Sencha\Architect\Cmd\6.2.0.103
```

The following step is to change PATHEXT enviroment varible. Change at user variables to have the least impact possible.

I change from

```
COM;.CMD;.EXE;.BAT;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

to

```
COM;.BAT;.EXE;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

The idea is to make windows run .bat files first than .exe files.
This is important because in sencha folder there is already an "sencha.exe" file. And in the command line if you type "sencha" it will execute "sencha.exe" instead of "sencha.bat".

This was the only solution that worked for because I'm very restricted when it comes to permissions.

Answer (score 1):

My System:-
Windows 8.1

Java Environments

- C:\JavaEnvironment\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
- C:\JavaEnvironment\Java\jdk1.7.0_75

I recently installed Oracle 11g XE and I received the mentioned error message when accessed "java" command at command prompt.

I checked my environment variables, checked the sequence (as mentioned by previous replies) and detected that my system PATH variable had following entry as first entry:
C:\OracleDatabase\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;

I changed the sequence and defined JDK path as first entry:

[image]

I replicated the same change to User Variable: Path

[image]

After finishing the above activity, I restarted the command prompt and executed java -version command and the problem had vanished. It displayed Java 8 as the current version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue but this was because i opened the command prompt ( windows machine ) and by default it opened the command prompt at :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

trying to execute basic command such as java -version would give me this error :

```
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Simply navigating out of system32 into C:\ and voila ! things are working
( guess in my case it was to do with being present inside system32 which would be a windows specific directory )

Answer (score 0):

I also found the following key in the Windows registry, changing it solved my problem:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Removed java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe from Below folder,

   C:\Windows\System32
2. Also in Eclipse -> Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Complier -> Compiler Compliance level -> 1.7(It was 1.8)

Answer (score -1):

Unistall Java 8 from your program list. BY following below steps:-

From your desktop, click on the Start Menu (or Start ball) at the lower left of your screen. 
Go to the Control Panel.
Click on Programs and Features.
Select Java8 and click Uninstall

Answer (score -1):

Kill all applications related to java in task manager and then delete the Java.exe , Javaw.exe and Jawaws.exe from C:\windows\System32

This should solve your problem... :)

Comment: can you please make it clear how would that solve the issue at hand?

Answer (score -2):

just did this and it worked

HKLM > SOFTWARE > JavaSoft > Java Runtime Environment

just manually change current version to 1.7 .

lol ... but it worked!